# Windows Explorer & custom shortcut file types

Tags: windows, explorer, file-type, startmenu

Windows has a flag in file registrations called "IsShortcut". When this flag is set, the file is automatically given the shortcut icon overlay and is treated as a shortcut in other ways (for instance, when you right click and select "Create Shortcut", it simply copies the file instead of generating a .lnk file). Microsoft uses this feature for ClickOnce Application References (extension `.appref-ms`).

We use this feature for a custom shortcut file type for our own software, and what we have found is that since Windows 10 (or possibly Windows 8), our custom shortcuts do not appear in the Start Menu. The Start Menu of course lists `.lnk` files, and it *does* include `.appref-ms` files as well, but our own file format, whose registration does not appear substantively different from `.appref-ms` files, is excluded from the Start Menu. The shortcut files are physically present within the Start Menu folder structure (`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`) but are ignored by Windows Explorer. Other shortcut types (`.lnk` and `.appref-ms`) in the same directory do show up.

What I'm looking for is some indication of how Windows Explorer determines which file formats it will include in the Start Menu, so that when developing a custom format, it can be indicated in the same manner. Our custom format worked fine in Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7, but the newer Start Menu design for some reason excludes our file format, even though it is marked `IsShortcut` in the same manner as `.appref-ms` files.

Is this possible to do? :-)

Comment: Do you implement IShellLink shell extension associated with your file extension?

Comment: We do not. The majority of the members of `IShellLink` are not possible to implement with our shortcuts. For instance, our shortcuts store one or more Application Name values which are then passed to a launcher. The exact path to the program file isn't known, and even if it were, there could be more than one. This makes it impossible to properly implement `GetPath`/`SetPath`.

This can't be how Explorer is determining which shortcuts to display, though, otherwise it would have to load & test every single shortcut file in order to show the list for a given folder. That would perform poorly.

Comment: Though... I suppose it does load and test every shortcut it actually displays, otherwise icon handlers wouldn't work. I guess it can't be ruled out that Explorer might use `IShellLink` as the semaphore for whether to display a given shortcut...

Comment: If you cannot correctly implement GetPath/SetPath you can try to return E_NOTIMPL. Starting from 8.1 links implement also IPropertyStore. And shell requests some properties like color, text and so on. And MAYBE (I'm not sure just hypothesis) shell requests something like PKEY_CanShowInStartMenu.

Comment: I suppose it's worth investigating. :-)

Comment: Okay, I've just gotten around to throwing that interface onto my type, and it did not help. In fact, I have "Launch folder windows in a separate process" enabled, and I found that the Explorer.exe driving the Start Menu wasn't even loading my DLL at all. I managed to get it to load my DLL by enabling the "Desktop" toolbar, where some of my icons are present and get treated properly according to their file registration, but browsing or searching the Start Menu did not trigger anything `IShellLinkW`-related. I do appreciate the suggestion, though; it was definitely worth trying :-)

Comment: I will check and answer you some later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the link in Windows 10 startmenu, `IPropertyStore.GetValue` must be implemented and return some unique string for `PKEY_AppUserModel_ID` property.

To show the icon in Windows 10 startmenu, `IExtractIconW.GetIconLocation` must be implemented and owner of the registry key with CLSID class (i.e. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{42465C3A-83D3-4310-B27D-F271DE372764}) must be "NT Service\TrustedInstaller"

Here is sample implementation (enhanced Jonathan Gilbert code):
https://github.com/publee/CustomShortcutFileType

Comment: Holy cow! I actually contacted Microsoft developer support on this and was told that Windows 10 just had a hardcoded list of filetypes it would show. I can't wait to try this out -- if it works, it'll restore a piece of functionality that's been missing from our app for years simply because Microsoft said it wasn't possible any more. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is working! Thanks so much! I've only run into one stumbling block.

My actual file type doesn't use simple verbs defined in the registry with RUNDLL32, it uses an `IContextMenuHandler` implementation that then calls CreateProcess. This does work, in that it launches the application, but the Start Menu does not close. Multiple shortcuts can be clicked in succession. Not sure how to tell the Start Menu it should close. I've asked about this in a separate question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050061/how-to-close-start-menu-with-custom-shortcut-that-launches-in-the-background

Comment: Strangely, I had it working based on your suggestions, and then through some refactoring, it suddenly stopped working, and I couldn't figure out why. But, one thing that had been bugging me is that the IDL supplied with the Windows SDK seems to omit `IExtractIconW`, so my IDL couldn't indicate that it was implemented. Having run out of other things to do, I synthesized a definition for `IExtractIconW` in my IDL, added it to the implemented list in my coclass, and suddenly the icons started showing up in the Start Menu again.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not the answer, but may help you in your investigations.)

I created and registred my own shell link extension. After Explorer restarts it uses my extension and asks different properties via IPropertyStore interface. Full log:

```
TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0 is created
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.QueryInterface IID_IShellLinkW out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.QueryInterface IID_IInitializeWithFile out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IInitializeWithFile.Initialize started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IInitializeWithFile.Initialize in AFileName=C:\Users\Dec\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Total Commander\1.mylnk
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IInitializeWithFile.Initialize in AOpenMode=STGM_READ
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IInitializeWithFile.Initialize out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IInitializeWithFile.Initialize finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.QueryInterface IID_IShellLinkW out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.QueryInterface IID_IShellLinkDataList out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkDataList.GetFlags started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkDataList.GetFlags out Result=E_NOTIMPL
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkDataList.GetFlags finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkW.GetPath started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkW.GetPath in AFileName=0C1FF058
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkW.GetPath in AFileNameLength=260
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkW.GetPath in @AFindData=0C1FEE08
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkW.GetPath in AFlags=SLGP_RAWPATH
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkW.GetPath out Result=E_NOTIMPL
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IShellLinkW.GetPath finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.QueryInterface IID_IPropertyStore out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey=PKEY_AppUserModel_ID (Caption: AppUserModelId, CanonicalName: System.AppUserModel.ID, Type: VT_LPWSTR)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=E_INVALIDARG
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey=PKEY_AppUserModel_PreventPinning (Caption: Prevent pinning, CanonicalName: System.AppUserModel.PreventPinning, Type: VT_BOOL)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out AData.vt=VT_BOOL
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out AData=0
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey={9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}, 23 (Caption: System.AppUserModel.ExcludedFromLauncher, CanonicalName: System.AppUserModel.ExcludedFromLauncher, Type: VT_BOOL)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out AData.vt=VT_BOOL
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out AData=0
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=S_OK
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey={9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}, 14 (Caption: Host environment, CanonicalName: System.AppUserModel.HostEnvironment, Type: VT_UI4)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=E_INVALIDARG
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey=PKEY_AppUserModel_StartPinOption (Caption: Start pin option, CanonicalName: System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption, Type: VT_UI4)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=E_INVALIDARG
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey={9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}, 18 (Caption: Installed by, CanonicalName: System.AppUserModel.InstalledBy, Type: VT_UI4)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=E_INVALIDARG
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey=PKEY_AppUserModel_IsDualMode (Caption: Is dual mode, CanonicalName: System.AppUserModel.IsDualMode, Type: VT_BOOL)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=E_INVALIDARG
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue started
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue in AKey=PKEY_Link_Arguments (Caption: Arguments, CanonicalName: System.Link.Arguments, Type: VT_LPWSTR)
    TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue out Result=E_INVALIDARG
  TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0.IPropertyStore.GetValue finished
TMyLinkExtension.07BA12F0 is destroyed
```

I tried to play with different values but still cant find the way to show my 1.mylnk file in the start menu but maybe this log will help you.

Comment: So this log is generated by opening the Start Menu? It's gathering details about your shortcut, but then ultimately deciding not to display it?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Maybe I must process more PropertyKeys in my sample (all of them?) to force Explorer show my link..

Comment: So, I called Microsoft customer support about this, and after months of deliberation (literally), they finally called back to tell me it was out of scope. They recommended posting on the customer support forums, so I did that: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7c88d220-2363-4cfb-8ae1-87be143d85b7/custom-shortcut-filetypes?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

The latest information suggests that this is in fact a bug in Windows Explorer. Look for two recent comments with the text "an offhand comment" and "another, very concise way to reproduce this issue."

Comment: I don't know if Stack Overflow notifies you about other people's answers or comments on them. In case it doesn't, and in case you're interested, I'm writing this comment to draw your attention back to this post so you can see user234878's answer, which appears to have comprehensively solved the problem. :-)